# Lighttpd - redirect a specific URL to another domain

Tags: webserver, lighttpd

I want to redirect a particular url to another domain..

For example, redirect www.site1.com to www.site2.com using lighttpd

Note: It should not redirect www.site1.com/abc to www.site2.com/abc (or) www.site2.com

I tried it. But it redirects all requests to site2.com

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$HTTP["host"] == "www.site1.com" {
    $HTTP["url"] =~ "^/$" {
        url.redirect = ( "" => "http://www.site2.com/" )
        url.redirect-code = 302
    }
}
```